# How come first entry not being selected using nth child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

The javascript is the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnHide').click(function() {
            $('td:nth-child(1)').nextUntil(':nth-child(4)').toggle();

        });
    });
```

and the html is as follows

```
<table id="tableone" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Row 0 Column 0</td>
    <td >Row 0 Column 1</td>
    <td >Row 0 Column 2</td>
    <td >Row 0 Column 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 1 Column 0</td>
    <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 Column 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2 Column 0</td>
    <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
<td>Row 2 Column 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 3 Column 0</td>
    <td>Row 3 Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 3 Column 2</td>
    <td>Row 3 Column 3</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Row 4 Column 0</td>
    <td>Row 4 Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 4 Column 2</td>
    <td>Row 4 Column 3</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Row 5 Column 0</td>
    <td>Row 5 Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 5 Column 2</td>
    <td>Row 5 Column 3</td>
</tr>


<input id="btnHide" type="button" value="Hide Columns"/>
```

Whatever I do I cant seem to find how to hide the first column also.. I have used 0 instead of 1 to see if it is indexed using 0 as the first entry, but that doesnt seem to work either.  How would I go about being able to select the first column also to collapse when the button is pressed

ADDED QUESTION:
Upon testing this in my mockup, I have realized that when that button is pressed, it collapses the columns in all tables on the page.  Since I am not a Javascript expert by any means, could someone point me to the right direction as far as how I could target specific tables. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`.nextUntil()` returns the elements *after* the original element, but not including the original element. Use [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) to add the original element into the set:

```
$('td:nth-child(1)').nextUntil(':nth-child(4)').addBack().toggle();
```

Comment: I just tried it and it worked perfectly!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess `.andSelf()` would do the same too

Comment: Yes, that's the deprecated function that `addBack` replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Hi' you can do it like this:

```
$('#btnHide').click(function() {
    $('td:not(td:nth-child(4))').toggle();

 });
```

here you are choosing every element except the element referred to the ":not()"